# Php Excel File Download With Readable format

Tags: php, excel, file, import, export-to-excel

I have tried to implement the excel file download in php. 
I have tried the below code file download.

```
ob_start();

echo "Hi This is Input! ";
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=test.xls");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Cache-Control: public");

ob_flush();
```

excel file download is seems fine. but downloaded excel file can't able to upload with php excel reader 2. when i tried to upload the test.xls file it seems the below error message

```
test.xml is not readable in excel_reader2.php
```

I want to import the excel file using excel reader 2.

is anything i have missed or anything i am doing wrong with the code

Any help much appreciation.

Comment: `xml` !== `xls`... how are you actually creating the content of this `test.xml` file? You show how you set the headers, but not how you create the actual content of the file.... unless you really believe that echoing "Hi This is Input! "; is creating a BIFF format .xls file through automagic and pixie dust

Comment: If you want to load an Excel file using excel_reader, then it needs to be a ___real___ BIFF format excel file, not simply a text file with an extension of .xls